# US Federal Census citation details and citation text using FTM for Mac

Tags: sources, census-records, family-tree-maker

I am working on US Federal Census records and cleaning up my sources.  What information needs to go into each section of the citation details and text?

Comment: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/2124/104 and http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/1417/104 are excellent guidance on this topic that you might wish to review. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3069/104 also talks explicitly about using FTM for Mac, which uses source templates based on Evidence Explained, by Elizabeth Shown Mills.

Comment: Interestingly, the third entry you mention genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3069/104 has been helpful and led to more questions to understand and deepen my knowledge of sourcing using FTM for Mac.

Answer (score 3):

It is your decision what goes in there.

At a minimum it should be sufficient information to allow someone else to take your reference **easily** find the source document and check your transcription of the data.

Website links can be helpful but are limited in that websites can disappear and or pages get moved.

I always attach an image to my source citation and in that way the original doesn't have to be searched for BUT you must always include the id for the record, so state enumeration district etc.

Comment: Colin, I appreciate your response.  I had extraction information and knew it was too much of the wrong information and would not help others to find the source document.  One question still nags... what is the purpose of the citation details and citation text?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice guide from ProGenealogists explaining how to do good citations of sources. I have nothing to do with them but I found their citation guide very useful.

http://www.progenealogists.com/citationguide.htm

Comment: Hi and welcome to Genealogy.SE! For simplicity's sake, could you summarize the relevant parts of the article here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have done a series of Blog posts on this subject:

http://ftmuser.blogspot.com/search/label/Census1940

> **How to Display Data ?**
>
> I have been thinking about the ways we can display our data, usually
>   for ourselves. For example, the 1940 Census.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Thanks :)